# Webpack 4 babel/at-loader jsx not recognized on single maschine

Tags: webpack

I'm currently facing a very strange error. I've migrated a custom webpack 3 config to webpack 4 using jsx (react) and typescript. It works on every machine flawlessly, except on one. That machine encounters the common Error "**You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type**".

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (48:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   renderCtaFigure() {
|     return (
>       <Motion
|         style={{
|           width: spring(
```

Which is triggered by any non-standard JavaScript code. Eg. the at-loader also reports:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  */
| export function objectToHtmlTags(
>   _object: Object,
|   recrusive: boolean = true
| ): string {
```

I've validated that they are up to spec configured:

```
 {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules(?!\/auw-framework)|bower_components|Public|typo3(?!(conf))\w*|sysext)/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          babelrc: true
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    exclude: /(bower_components|Public|typo3|sysext)/,
    include: __dirname, // suggested by comments from the at-loader issues
    use: ["babel-loader", "awesome-typescript-loader"]
  },
```

Their corresponding `.babelrc` and `tsconfig.json` are like following:

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/react"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017", "esnext", "dom"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "./web",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,

    "inlineSources": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useBabel": true,
    "useCache": true,
    "useTranspileModule": true,
    "forceIsolatedModules": true,
    "babelCore": "@babel/core" // needed for Babel v7
  },
  "exclude": [
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/browser",
    "node_modules",
    "vendor",
    "typo3_src",
    "web/typo3",
    "sysext/**/*",
    "**/Configuration/**/*.ts",
    "**/TypoScript/**/*.ts",
    "typo3conf/ext/*/Configuration",
    "**/TsConfig/**"
  ]
}
```

I've now spent hours finding and trying various solutions, including completely reinstalling node and any other node-powered things. Everything I could think of do exactly match my machine on which it works.

Anyone suggestions for further debugging?

Comment: Did you find it's solution?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error and the same issue that it worked everywhere. Just not in a Gitlab CI Docker container. Even when i pulled that exact same container and ran every command manually, it worked. The only thing that fixed it was to remove a build folder from the `exclude` list in the Babel config.

**Old**

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|build)/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
        //presets and plugins in .babelrc
    }
}
```

**New**

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
        //presets and plugins in .babelrc
    }
}
```

Still not sure why, because babel should not need the build folder, and it does work everywhere else. But it fixed the issue, so maybe try to remove the excludes for now.